# How to restrict same promotion coupon's addition to multiple carts

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I'm trying to find a way to restrict a public coupon from being used by the same customer in more than one order.
Eg: I have a public coupon "`10DOLLAROFF2021`"
I need to make this coupon available for all the customers for single order. Once used, the same customer should get some error saying this has already been used when trying to use it again.
Is this functionality available on Sitecore commerce already?

Any suggestions on how we can achieve if not available already.

```
Sitecore Version: 9.2
Commerce Version: 9.2
```

Comment: This doesn't come OOTB and needs to be customised. I haven't done this myself but just a thought. See the Customer Orders and check if any promotion copun already applied matches the coupons applied to cart.  Explore the Qualification Condition "Current Customer Has Pruchased [specific]" you may have to make similar custom qualification condition to disallow the user from using the same coupon again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's How I would do this:

1. Create a Custom Block to be added to the customer (UsedCouponsComponent). this component would have the list of coupons already used
2. Extend `ICreateOrderPipeline` with a Custom Block that would check if a coupon is part of the order. If yes add it to the UsedCouponsComponent then add UsedCouponsComponent to the current customer entity.
3. Extend `IDiscoverPromotionsPipeline` with a custom block after FilterPromotionsByCouponBlock to filter and remove any coupons already used by the customer.